# Single-line solution for list items to dictionary comparison

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```py
region_dict = {'france':'West', 'germany':'Central', 'italy':'South', 'poland':'East', 'norway':'North'}

mylist = ['FRANCE','gERMANY', 'iTaLy', 'poland', 'Norway']

for item in mylist:
    if item.lower() in region_dict:
         region = region_dict[item.lower()]
         print(region)
```

I am trying to compare list values to dict keys and get the dict values. This works, but is there a way to do it in a single line? No real reason other than it looks nicer, in my opinion.

I've tried doing:

```py
region = item for item in mylist if item.lower() in region_dict
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
region = [region_dict.get(item.lower()) for item in mylist if item.lower() in region_dict.keys()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If region_dict keys are always lowercase, this should work

```
region_dict = {'france':'West', 'germany':'Central', 'italy':'South', 'poland':'East', 'norway':'North'}

mylist = ['FRANCE','gERMANY', 'iTaLy', 'poland', 'Norway']

print(
[region_dict[a.lower()] for a in mylist if a.lower() in region_dict]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a version without list comprehension:

```
list(filter(None, map(region_dict.get, map(str.lower, mylist))))
```

**output:**

```
['West', 'Central', 'South', 'East', 'North']
```

Answer (score -1):

List comprehensions are written in brackets:

```
region = [item for item in mylist if item.lower() in region_dict]
```